# How to add three zeroes to the end of a datetime string in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

I have data like this `2020/08/05 05:34:05.000` i tried to get the similar output by using `to_char(column,'YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS.FF3')` getting error "Date format not recognized". how to append these 000 at the end after seconds ?

I tried using `to_char(column,'YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS')` which gives me `2020/08/05 05:34:05` but i want three zeroes should append at the end is it possible without hardcoding zeroes to get the 000 ?

Comment: As described in the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Format-Models.html#GUID-EAB212CF-C525-4ED8-9D3F-C76D08EEBC7A) for `FF` datetime format element: *Valid in timestamp and interval formats, but not in `DATE` formats.* Because date has no fractional seconds. But casting it to timestamp has no any difference compared to "hardcoding" zeroes since they do not exist in the original data. You may use `YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS".000"`

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the column datatype is `DATE`. `DATE` datatype does not support fractional seconds but you can cast it into a `TIMESTAMP`.

```
to_char(CAST(column AS TIMESTAMP), 'YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS.FF3')
```